# Publishing a Magazine in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, newsletter, publishing-site

My client wants to create a company internal magazine on Sharepoint 2007. Actually I never seen anything like this in any Sharepoint site before.

- An "issuing system" (like issue #1, october) is required. Stories (news) should be grouped into issues.
- Users should post their stories (like best practices) which will be approved and published under an issue.
- default.aspx should display the latest issue. (e.g. this month's magazine)
- It should also be possible to see all the news and issues in an archive view.

I know asking like "how can this be achieved?" is a bit glib. But it would be good if you can point my a way on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have done this before, under MOSS 2007. These were the components of the solution
1. Create a page layout for issues
2. Create content type for articles, based on regular article it should contain reference to issue, column and position within issue. Make those values editable in the edit mode of the page.
2. Create a web part that will show article teasers for the issue homepage, it should respect the abovementioned issue, column and position values
3. Embed the web part in the issue layout. We had 3 of thoses web parts on the page, one for each column.

This is it, you create an instance of an issue and start filling it with articles, once you create an article configured to appear in the issue, it shows up by itself.
Use publishing and approval mechanism for approval, use the home page setting of the web site to change the default page with every new issue